# how to retrieve the data path in browser?

Tags: php, mysql

hi 
Am having task to perform someone help me out.I have designed a search page(will be like steps added) which searches all the datas from the database.I kept in different php files for each layer.Now I have to get its path save it through database and display it through the browser.the already searched datas have to get display as path in browser and when user  clicks it have to display the datas of that path.Can anyone suggest some ideas to do this?

Comment: Which path? File path, relative path or absolute path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, here, but either the $_SERVER or $_GET variables should help you out.  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] will be a string equal to whatever the path + filename + args you're calling your script with.  It sounds, though, like you could probably do all this with HTTP GET arguments - http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php